# Visual Basic .NET - Change color of an item in a ListBox

Tags: vb.net, colors, listbox

so I've been working a little project for home usage, but I'm stuck on it. I'm trying to change the color of a selected item in a ListBox with a button, ComboBox, and of course a listBox. So I have almost everything on my program ready besides the color changing. I have my ListBox with items in it, and I want to be able to change the color of the selected item when pushing a button (The ComboBox has the colors in it such as White, Green, and red. The ListBox has all of my items in it, and of course the button will just change the ListBox selected item with the selected item in the ComboBox.) I'm not sure if this made much sense, if it didn't just let me know and I'll better explain.

Here's a images to better explain:

[image]

I've looked at other post asking this question, but they just confuse me. Thank you all for your help.

Comment: There's no standard functionality for that.  If you want your items to look other than the standard way then you have to draw them yourself.  If you search for "owner draw listbox" then you should find plenty of relevant information.

Comment: Thanks, also do you know away to count how many items are in your listbox? so i can have a button and when it's used it will change label1's text to the amount?

Comment: `ListBox1.Items.Count`

Comment: SO is not a substitute for performing a simple web search or for reading the MSDN documentation. We're here to help you with problems, not so that you don't have to bother trying to find existing information.